# How to copy a number from one page to another and add or subtract to it

Tags: wordpress, copy, price

I am creating a member page with 13 different categories of members. When the member logs in they are able to see their price for a product we sell. The customers are not meant to be able to actually buy the product on our website but only see the price.
I have set up different member categories with the WP Members Addon so thats all fine.

Now Id like to create a base price which easily can be edited every Monday and the other 12 sites should load that price automatically +/- 0,15 as below:

14.55
14.70
14.85
15.00 > This is the main number and changes every Monday. 
15.15
15.30
...

To make it simple I would like to only change the main number every Monday so nothing can get wrong either. Is there any way to do this? Kind of new to advanced WordPress stuff. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [advanced custom field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) with [option set on](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/), in that case you will only change that field globally.